# ¿Cómo unir diferentes clases para dar un mensaje, definido en main()?

Tags: java

¿Cómo unir diferentes clases para mostrar un mensaje? Esta es mi clase `Principal`:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String cadena;
        System.out.println ("Hola");
    }
}
```

Clase `Sujeto`:

```
public class Sujeto  {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String nombre = "Javier";
    }   
}
```

Clase `Saludar` :

```
public class Saludar {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println ("¿Como estas?");
    }
}
```

Estoy en pleno aprendizaje de Java y quisiera saber como unir estas tres clases para dar un solo mensaje. Tengo entendido que debería hacerlo en la clase Principal, y después de eso en el System.out.println se deben concatenar con el signo +.

¿Es necesario declarar algo más dentro del código? Cabe aclarar que estoy empezando a usar jdk y a trabajar con bloc de notas. Gracias

Comment: Podrías hacerlo todo en una clase con System.out.println("Hola " + nombre + " Como estas"); , te recomiendo que uses Visual Code para programar en vez del bloc de notas.

Comment: todas son clases principales porque tienen main.

Answer (score 4):

Recuerda que la ejecución de tu programa tomará solo el método `main` de tu clase principal, si quieres imprimir los textos definidos en los demás métodos `main` definidos en otras clases, puedes llamarlos de esta forma ya que estan definidos como estaticos.

```
    Sujeto.main(args);
    Saludar.main(args);
```

Supongamos que el método `main()` de tu clase `Principal` es el punto de inicio de tu aplicación, aquí llamaríamos los demás métodos `main()`:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cadena;

        System.out.println("Hola");

        //llama métodos main
        Sujeto.main(args);
        Saludar.main(args);


    }

}



public class Sujeto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Javier");

    }

}


public class Saludar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("¿Como estas?");

    }

}
```

de esta forma la salida de tu programa sería:

```
Hola
Javier
¿Como estas?
```